# Calling prepare for post-processing fails to apply aspects (cdk.Tags)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Due to a strict AWS governance policy we are required to apply certain tags (resource name tag and AWS service tag... ikr?) on many CloudFormation resources (we are pushing back on this, but it may require time). Applying the tags can be difficult to achieve, especially with high level constructs such as CdkPipeline, which abstracts away a lot of the underlying resources. Some options present themselves:

- Extending the CdkPipeline class and using [escape hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html) in the constructor to apply tags with cdk.Tags.of(...).add(...). This works fine, however more resources will be added through adding stages to the pipeline. Nevertheless, in case of utter need we can intercept these calls and apply tags where needed (e.g. overriding addApplicationStage, providing subclasses for CdkStage).
- I was looking into a more automated approach using the protected prepare method offered by the Construct class (again I subclass CdkPipeline for this). This will make change before synthesis and will be applied depth first in the construct tree. While we are successful in overriding properties, but using the recommended approach of cdk.Tags.of(child).add(...) does not apply the tag aspects. It's hard to derive from the code what's causing this. Nevertheless, we can still override the tags using addOverride on the CfnResource classes. Here is the code snippet:

  ```
  private adaptRoles(startNode=this.node) {
    const stack = cdk.Stack.of(this);

    startNode.children.forEach((child) => {
      if (child instanceof iam.Role) {
        const roleResource = child.node.findChild('Resource') as iam.CfnRole;
        const roleName = `some-prefix-${stack.getLogicalId(roleResource)}`.slice(0, 64);

        roleResource.addPropertyOverride('PermissionsBoundary', `arn:aws:iam::${stack.account}:policy/some-boundary`);
        roleResource.addPropertyOverride('RoleName', roleName);

        // cdk.Tags.of(child|roleResource).add(...) has no effect, need to resort to low level override
        roleResource.addPropertyOverride('Tags', [
          {
            Key: 'Technology',
            Value: 'iam',
          },
          {
            Key: 'Name',
            Value: roleName,
          },
        ]);
      }

      this.adaptRoles(child.node);
    });
  }

  protected prepare() {
    // makes no difference changing the order of the statements
    this.adaptRoles();
    super.prepare();
  }
  ```

This will recursively iterate through the Construct tree and apply tags to IAM roles (imported IAM roles won't be affected cause they won't be created within the scope of the CdkPipeline).

The prepare method, from what I gather, will also be removed in CDK v2. However this is months down the line and I hope to have made strides relaxing the tagging policy by then, so that hopefully these workarounds won't be necessary anymore by that time.

Thanks for any insights! I figured I'd search for possible explanations first before this should be regarded as a potential bug.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. The question was how to do it without prepare and why the Tag aspect wasn't working. In the mean I figured out a potential answer but I also stray away from overriding the prepare method and we have started using CDK Aspects to make sure conventions are respected.